# Software interrupts on AVR

Tags: posix, interrupt, avr, system-calls

I understand that x86 machine code can make POSIX system calls using software interrupts ([by entering a 32-bit value corresponding to a kernel function into the EAX register of the processor and then executing INT 0x80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29#Real_mode)).

I'm looking into designing a small Unix-like operating system for the AVR architecture for fun and learning. How do software interrupts like x86's `INT` work on AVR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't. AVR has no provision for software interrupts. If you need to generate an interrupt from software then you will need to convince some piece of hardware to generate it instead. Otherwise just use a JSR as normal.

Comment: Jump to SubRoutine, a different opcode (although AVR uses CALL et alia).

Comment: If JSR behaves similarly to software interrupts, why are software interrupts the preferred method on architectures that support it? Is it due to the way the processor handles other incoming interrupts while it's executing an ISR? Also, can you use JSR to make POSIX syscalls on x86?

Comment: INT pushes more registers onto the stack.